# converting/casting String to PHP associate array

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array

I have a below string getting as a response from a Payment gateway

> Array ( [status] => 1 [msg] => 3 out of 3 Transactions Fetched
>   Successfully [transaction_details] => Array ( [KE_5bd951c08f6e5] =>
>   Array ( [mihpayid] => 7595132911 [request_id] => [bank_ref_num] =>
>   183045739981 [amt] => 207.00 [transaction_amount] => 207.00 [txnid] =>
>   KE_5bd951c08f6e5 [additional_charges] => 0.00 [productinfo] =>
>   hyderabad-open-art-competition-childrens-day-special-1 [firstname] =>
>   poornima gowda [bankcode] => HDFB [udf1] => 9483 [udf3] => [udf4] =>
>   [udf5] => [field2] => [field9] => success [error_code] => E000
>   [addedon] => 2018-10-31 12:24:57 [payment_source] => payu [card_type]
>   => [error_Message] => NO ERROR [net_amount_debit] => 207 [disc] => 0.00 [mode] => NB [PG_TYPE] => HDFCNB [card_no] => [udf2] => 16516 [status] => success [unmappedstatus] => captured [Merchant_UTR] =>
>   [Settled_At] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) [KE_5bd94072a5706] => Array (
>   [mihpayid] => 7594804413 [request_id] => [bank_ref_num] => [amt] =>
>   103.50 [transaction_amount] => 103.50 [txnid] => KE_5bd94072a5706 [additional_charges] => 0.00 [productinfo] =>
>   hyderabad-open-art-competition-childrens-day-special-1 [firstname] =>
>   lavanya [bankcode] => [udf1] => 9483 [udf3] =>
>   hyderabad-open-art-competition-childrens-day-special-1 [udf4] =>
>   [udf5] => [field2] => [field9] => Marked bounced as transaction has
>   timed out [error_code] => E408 [addedon] => 2018-10-31 11:11:07
>   [payment_source] => payu [card_type] => [error_Message] => NO ERROR
>   [net_amount_debit] => 0.00 [disc] => 0.00 [mode] => - [PG_TYPE] =>
>   [card_no] => [udf2] => 1279 [status] => failure [unmappedstatus] =>
>   bounced [Merchant_UTR] => [Settled_At] => ) [KE_5bd95e74f2421] =>
>   Array ( [mihpayid] => 7595382223 [request_id] => [bank_ref_num] =>
>   [amt] => 103.50 [transaction_amount] => 103.50 [txnid] =>
>   KE_5bd95e74f2421 [additional_charges] => 0.00 [productinfo] =>
>   hyderabad-open-art-competition-childrens-day-special-1 [firstname] =>
>   Diya Chakraborty [bankcode] => SBIB [udf1] => 9483 [udf3] =>
>   hyderabad-open-art-competition-childrens-day-special-1 [udf4] =>
>   [udf5] => [field2] => [field9] => Marked dropped as transaction has
>   timed out [error_code] => E501 [addedon] => 2018-10-31 13:19:10
>   [payment_source] => payu [card_type] => [error_Message] => Bank was
>   unable to authenticate. [net_amount_debit] => 0.00 [disc] => 0.00
>   [mode] => NB [PG_TYPE] => SBINB [card_no] => [udf2] => 14079 [status]
>   => failure [unmappedstatus] => dropped [Merchant_UTR] => [Settled_At] => ) ) )

How can I convert this to typical PHP array?

I tried using `eval`

```
eval("\$array = $str;");
```

Nothing is working for me. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

**var_dump reponse:**

```
/var/www/html/prod/application/controllers/Booking.php:3104:string '<pre>Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [msg] => 3 out of 3 Transactions Fetched Successfully
    [transaction_details] => Array
        (
            [KE_5bd951c08f6e5] => Array
                (
                    [mihpayid] => 7595132911
                    [request_id] => 
                    [bank_ref_num] => 183045739981
                    [amt] => 207.00
                    [transaction_amount] => 207.00
                    [txnid] => KE_5bd951c08f6e5
                    [additional_charges] => 0.00
   '... (length=4499)
```

I am using CURL to request to URL and passing params like below

```
$c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $wsUrl);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qs);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $o = curl_exec($c);

        return $o;
```

Comment: Can you show how you get the response from the gateways - are you sure it's not passing JSON and this is being processed?

Comment: I think it unlikely that an API returns a print_r formatted string. Isn't it more likely you are using it wrong? How about some more code context?

Comment: That IS a TYPICAL PHP ARRAY as output by `print_r()` Please show us the code you use to get to this output

Comment: it is returning a string.  you can see the var_dump of response i got in question.

Answer (score 0):

used this function to reverse form the array from the prin_r() output

```
https://gist.github.com/simivar/037b13a9bbd53ae5a092d8f6d9828bc3
```